# Create a link on the fly when a user enters a code in a form box

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form....

```
<form id="orderform" method="post" orderform="" name="">
  <table width="533" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0" id="ordertable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Product Code</td>
      <td>Meterage</td>
      <td>Sample Img</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
      <td class="prodcode">
        <input type="text" id="prodcode" name="prodcode">
      </td>
      <td class="meterage">
        <input type="text" id="meterage" name="meterage">
      </td>
      <td class="imgsample"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

What i would like is when a user clicks out of the box on the prodcode it searches a folder for the image reference...creates a link on under the imgsample header for that particular item using the prodCode they entered...

http://www.mylink.com/images/folder/sub-folder/imageref.jpg

Is this an impossible task, any ideas?

Comment: Please note when i say it searches a folder, it may have subfolder (categories of images) and ill only have the product code to search for... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are asking for.

```
$("#prodcode").blur(function() {
  $.post(
         'yourpage.php', //this page reads the image code and gives you the image location
         { action: 'searchimage', imgreference: $('#prodcode').val() },
         function(data) { 
             //export the link as data            
             $("td.imgsample").html('<img src="'+data+'"/>');
         }
        );
});
```

Comment: Have i got this wrong or is the yourpage.php a search script to find the directory?

Comment: Yes, the page to which you send the code to get the image location.

Comment: Wow...very cool!  Let me try this bad boy out.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: You need to output the image location with an `echo` or `print` statement at the end

Comment: yourpage.php receives the post prodcode?  Then all i need to do is search, create a link http://www. e.t.c and then echo it at the end and it gets added to the data...

Comment: You got it. That's exactly what it should do :D

Comment: Hi Starx it didnt work :(  Could it because of the path to the file?

Comment: THe blur event works, i tried it with an alert function.  But nothing is getting added to the td. I decided to simply write a link in the page without any query just to test it would get added.

Comment: try to see what `data` holds... with `alert(data)` after `function(data) {` and post the output here.

Comment: THank you starx...it was my path that was wrong.  It was because i was using the path from the JS file, not the page.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

bind to the blur event of the prodcode input,
when it blurs issue an ajax call to the server to get the right Url
and at the callback just build the link and set it as the html of .imgsample

Comment: This sounds exactly what im after, do you know of any code samples to help me put this in place?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a link and you need to ensure it isd the closest table cell that gets it and you have latest jquery you could try something like

```js
$("#prodcode").bind("blur", function() {
    var linkStr = "<a href="http://www.mylink.com/images/folder/sub-folder/"+ $("#prodcode").val()+".jpg";
    $("#prodcode").closest("td.imgsample").html(linkStr);
});
```

Comment: This is very cool, but not quite what i'm after.  Sorry if my description wasn't quite right!  I need it to search the folder and sub folders to generate the link...